# What would be the best way to implement a text size accessibility feature?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, accessibility, user-experience

I need to implement a feature into a web app i'm building that will increase text size / window zoom to assist in reading text.

The best method in my head would be to simulate a browser zoom so that my media queries are also taken into account and the layout doesn't break, but i'm not sure of the best way / if this is possible.

CSS zoom isn't really an option due to the framework using media queries.

Any help / other ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Personally, I always use the browser zoom (usually ctrl++ or cmd++ or ctrl+wheelmouse) instead of any apps builtin zooming tool, mainly because I know where my browser zoom is and I don't have to think to do it.  For apps that have their own, I have to find the tool (could be upper left or upper right, could be a separate icon or part of a toolbar, it could be hidden unless I tab to it, etc).  However, before using the browser zoom, I check if the 'reading mode' is available.  This typically isn't available for real apps as much as it is for simple websites but it might be worth checking into.

Comment: Do not set font sizes unless they are relative units (as in, do not do `body {font-size:10px;}` as Bootstrap does, but maybe `body {font-size:100%;}` if you feel you must set the font size at all). Then the web page will honor the user's font size preferences and you need to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as @slugolicious said, you probably should be steering users to use their browser's inbuilt browser zooming features.

However, it's entirely possible this is a client/business requirement, so I'll suggest something.

Your best bet is to place a CSS class on your content holding element that adjusts the user's font size.

Here's some css classes:

```
#content.font-lg {
    font-size: 125%;
}

#content.font-xl {
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

And to trigger them, some JavaScript:

```
function onLargeFontButtonClick() {
    var element = document.getElementById('content');
    element.className = 'font-lg';
}

function onExtraLargeFontButtonClick() {
    var element = document.getElementById('content');
    element.className = 'font-xl';
}

function onNormalFontButtonClick() {
    var element = document.getElementById('content');
    element.className = '';
}
```

If you already have classes on your content area, you might want to use += instead for the classname, possibly removing instances of the other font class. Adjust to your needs.

I hope this helps!